# Grails BelongsTo with conditional query

Tags: grails, constraints, conditional-statements, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two domain classes with a one to many relationship. Let’s call them the OneClass and the ManyMetadataClass.

```
class OneClass {

    // ... some variables


    belongsTo = [version:ManyMetadataClass]

}

class ManyMetadataClass {

    String attribute
    int value

    hasMany = [
        OneClass,
        AnotherSimilarToOneClass,
        YetAnotherOneTypeClass
        // ...
    ]
}
```

The ManyMetadataClass is intended to store attribute value pairs for many different domain classes similar to the OneClass.

As previously state the OneClass "belongsTo" i.e. is the 1 in a 1:m relationship with ManyMetadataClass. However, only rows with a specific attribute value (attribute=versionControl) in the ManyMetadataClass are relevant to the OneClass.

My question is as follows: Is there any way to ensure at the domain class level that only rows from the ManyMetadataClass with attribute = versionControl can be selected from within the OneClass?

Thanks in advance

Some observations:

- I can achieve this at the Controller and View level, but this involves
  a lot of code and is harder to ensure no incorrect data is stored
  within the OneClass
- I could split the ManyMetadataClass into separate tables one per attribute, but this would result in a large amount of tables making maintaining the DB more tedious

Comment: After some reserch I think adding a custom "validator" with the OneClass constraints may solve the problem, however I haven't yet figured out how to do this. If anyone has experience with custom validators, I would apreciate their input

Comment: Looks exactly like what Hibernate does to discriminate table-per-class  (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass) instances. Grails, though, does not support table-per-class mapping, only table-per-subclass. Don't you want to review your database mapping?

Comment: So does that meen I'm out of luck?

Comment: The opposite - you might want to create a Groovy class for each concrete `OneClass` and still map to the same database (if that's of any importance). if it's applicable, it should be a way easier solution than key-value pair collection that `OneClass` seems to be.

Comment: The motivation for using just the single ManyMetadataClass with key-value pairs was to keep down the number of tables in the database making it (hopefully) easier to maintain and backup. But as you say, in the worst case scenario, I could have separate version control tables per OneClass